# Ubuntu one instruction for syncing of large ammount of data

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, ubuntu-one

I have a problem,

I wish to sync about 20gb of documents and other files between computers.
i have buyed extra space and now have 45 gb so i can have space if it grows.

I have started ubuntu one on both mashines my laptop, ubuntu 12.04
and desktop with ubuntu 11.10 both 64bit

i needed data on my laptop faster then ubuntu one could deliver them there via ubuntu one server. So i used filezilla to sincronize them while ubuntu one was running on both mashines.

What happend is that ubuntu one started to make subfolders with folders
an example

My laptop has folder /home/username/folder1 with all empty subfolders and no files in them and

now it has a folder /home/username/folder1/folder1 which is syncing with desktop mashine

now the files from laptop come to desktop via ubuntu one server.

and keep makeing folder on desktop /home/username/folder1/folder1
with files form laptop i suspect.

laptop is not receveving any files that are directly desktop folders, so has folder /home/username/folder1 with all empty subfolders and no files in them.

on one.ubuntu.com all folder and files look normal like on my desktop
I have waited for about a week for it, it seems this problem will not go away without some help.

Can anyone help me understand what happend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that server has folder with same subfolders
But i still do not understand how they were created on the server in the first place.